# Positive Definite Matrix Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ (symmetric) positive definite matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $A$ admits a factorization $A = LL^\top$ where $L$ is an invertible lower triangular matrix. In fact, a general square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if it admits a decomposition $A = PP^\top$ where $P$ is an invertible matrix.

The Cholesky decomposition seems to be the canonical way to decompose a positive definite matrix in such a way. But, what about other possible decompositions? For example, if $PP^\top = A = LL^\top$, what can one say about the relationship between the matrices $P$ and $L$? Do they share spectral properties? Are there infinitely many such decompositions? Can they be parametrized in some way?

Comment: For any pair of real square matrices $P$ and $L$ such that $PP^T=LL^T$, we must have $P=LQ$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$.

Comment: Your statement "In fact, a general square matrix..." requires a speciific definition of positive definite to be true.  It's an ugly fact about working over $\mathbb R$ that there are multiple definitions of positive definite.  These problems go away when working over $\mathbb C$-- and Cholesky still exists there.